# Fourier Transform calculation

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

I am trying to calculate the Fourier Transform of
$$f(x)=\exp(-\frac{|x|^2}{2}).
$$
Thus, I am looking at the integral
$$
\hat{f}(u)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-\frac{|x|^2}{2}) \cdot \exp(ix\cdot u) dx.
$$
I can't figure out how to evaluate this integral.  Am I trying the wrong approach to calculate the transform or should I be able the integral.  Note the integral is a Lebesgue integral.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second exponential inside the integral?  If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then what does the argument mean?

Comment: Presumably it's a dot product.

Comment: This is Proposition 8.24 in Folland's Real Analysis

Comment: Do you know how to do this in $R^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just see the special case first in $R^3$, that's $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, then you can handle the general case. So, we have

$$ f(u_1,u_2,u_3)= \int_{{R}^3} e^{-|x|^2}e^{-ix.u}dx$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)}e^{-i(x_1u_1+x_2u_2+x_3 u_3)}dx_1dx_2dx_3 $$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x_1^2+ix_1u_1)}dx_1\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x_2^2+ix_2u_2)}dx_2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x_3^2+ix_3u_3)}dx_3  $$

$$ = \prod_{k=1}^{3}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x_k^2+ix_ku_k)}dx_k = \prod_{k=1}^{3}\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{4}u_k^2 } = {\pi}^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{4}(u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2)}= {\pi}^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{4}|u|^2}.$$

Now, you can figure out the general case easily. Note that, for evaluating the above integrals, we first competed the square then use the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\exp(x)\exp(y)=\exp(x+y)$, and complete the square.