# Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of $e^{-\|x\|}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I'm stuck in the calculation of the Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of $$(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto\exp(-\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}).$$
I know how to compute the result for each $n$ odd (see e.g.   [1]: [Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460116/fourier-transform-of-e-x)), but also in this case I don't know a closed formula and, for $n$ even, I don't know how to procede.
Can anyone give a closed formula in $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and show how to calculate it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Due to radial simmetry it is enough to compute

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i\omega x_1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}e^{-\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}}\,dx_2\,dx_3\ldots dx_ndx_1$$
and the measure of $x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2=\rho^2$ [is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere) $\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\rho^{n-2}$, so the previous integral equals
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-i\omega x_1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\rho^{n-2} e^{-\sqrt{x_1^2+\rho^2}}\,d\rho\,dx_1 $$

Comment: but the innermost integral is simple to compute (by integration by parts) only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had missed that when n is odd integration by parts do the job. But again it is not clear to me what to do when n is even...

Comment: Where did you find the result for $n=2$? It looks to me that is depends on the unpleasant integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx = K_1(1)$.

Comment: I assumed it was simple to compute but now I'm stuck in the same problem. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use $e^{-a}=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty\exp\big(-t^2-\frac{a^2}{4t^2}\big)\,dt$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1819647)) at $a=\|x\|$:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-i\omega x-\|x\|}\,dx&=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left(-i\omega x-\frac{\|x\|^2}{4t^2}\right)dx\,dt
\\\color{gray}{[x=2ty]}\qquad&=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}(2t)^n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-2i\omega ty-\|y\|^2}\,dy\,dt
\\\color{gray}{[\text{gaussian integral}]}&=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}(2t)^n\pi^{n/2}e^{-\|\omega\|^2 t^2}\,dt
\\\color{gray}{[\text{gamma integral}]}&=\frac{2^n\pi^{(n-1)/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}{\left(1+\|\omega\|^2\right)^{(n+1)/2}}.
\end{align}