# How to solve this oscillatory integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|-i x\cdot c}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, asymptotics

What I try to do is calculating the result of this oscillatory integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|-i x\cdot c}dx$, where $|x|$ is the 2-norm of $x$, $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a constant vector, and $x\cdot c$ is dot product.

Does anyone has any hint for this integral? Thank you so much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569910/fourier-transform-in-mathbbrn-of-e-x

Comment: @Bob Thanks for your comment! That's very helpful.